# How to highlight multiple values with MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, charts, highlight, mpandroidchart

Is it possible to highlight several values in [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) ?

I highlight one value thanks to : barChart.highlightValue(high[0]) but how to highlight 2 values..

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes**, that is possible.

The library has a method called `highlightValues(Highlight[] highs)`.

This method allows to provide an array of `Highlight` objects to highlight multiple values.

Example:

```
Highlight h1 = new Highlight(...); // 1st value to highlight
Highlight h2 = new Highlight(...); // 2nd value to highlight

chart.highlightValues(new Highlight[] {h1, h2});
```

An **in-depth tutorial** on highlighting can be found [**here**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Highlighting).

Answer (score 0):

The code in Kotlin

```
barChart.highlightValues(arrayOf(
    Highlight(),
    Highlight()
))
```